# C# Read huge image into array

Tags: c#, arrays, image

I have huge images (1.800MP @ 8bit or 16bit), all grayscale, no alpha, transparency or other stuff.

They may come as png, tiff, bmp, or even jpeg, so I need an image library to handle the reading, decompression and stuff.

After this, I just want to get an array with the grayscale pixel values out - preferrably 2d, but 1d is also alright. It also may be `ushort` all the time, even for the 8bit images.

I tried using the buid-int `BitmapImage` of C# - no luck, just throws exceptions for images this large.

Any other libraries that can give me the grayscale values, without hassle?

Comment: I used to openCV library .NET wrapper for  image processing, but don't remember name. Maybe it's overkill for your needs

Comment: Bitmap class, call lockbits, bam!

Comment: Have to look to https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp, it can handle many format and apply the grayscale transform to your picture.

Comment: What exceptions are thrown?  What code throws the exceptions?  Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It will be faster if you use simple FileReader to read the content and generate your own array rather then looking for a library.

Comment: No, as I said, images come in a variety of formats and thus different encodings and compressions need to be handled. Just reading the FileStream does not give me the pixel-values.